# How to delete overlay in an Android modified Holo button?

Tags: android, button, styles, overlay, android-theme

I have this style for Buttons in my Android app, but I don't want that little shadow.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Primary" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
</style>
```

The button looks like this:
[Button image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0q4p4z87vlpevp/Snip20150224_1.png?dl=0)

Which item have to add in order to delete the overlay?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this shadow effect related to the Material Design scheme?  Normally buttons do not have shadow effects by default.  If so, then you will have to look into how to force your buttons to be without the extra dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I was applying the Material Light theme, so I changed it to my style and when I run the app no overlay is showed. Thanks.